# Why do we do '< /dev/null' in certain shell commands

Tags: bash, shell

A shell construct confused me recently, what's the difference between

```
while ! nc -z $HOST $PORT >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null; do
```

and

```
while ! nc -z $HOST $PORT >/dev/null 2>&1 ; do
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The purpose of `< /dev/null` is to send EOF to a program immediately when tries to read from its standard input. It also means that the standard input is cut from receiving input from any other sources e.g. terminal.

The `/dev/null` is a special device in Unix which consumes everything *written* to it but signals EOF whenever commands tries to *read* from it without actually providing any actual data to read from.

The re-directions  `>/dev/null 2>&1` mean that redirect all standard output produced by the command to the null device which it consumes and redirect all error stream output(2) to the console.

Answering to another OP's question

#### So what happens if I don't send EOF to nc? I have try it and the script also worked

Nothing is *expected* to happen. By doing `</dev/null` we just signal the `nc` to not expect to read anything from standard input.

---

Another classic example of why you would need this is when using `ssh` if incorrectly used with a while loop. Consider an example, if you have a file `servers.txt` containing a list of server names and want to do an operation over `ssh` for all the hosts. You would do something like

```
while read -r server; do
    ssh "$server" "uname -a"
done < servers.txt
```

You could think this being pretty straight forward with nothing expected to go wrong. But it does!

`ssh` will read from standard input. You have already added a `read` command with an input redirection over the file, so it also reads from standard input. The logic will be screwed up because after the first `read` command, the `ssh` will end up swallowing rest of the standard input which is undesired in your case.

So what do we do? We close the standard input of `ssh` by doing `</dev/null` as

```
ssh "$server" "uname -a" < /dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

`>` redirects stdout : What your code prints

`2>` redirects stderr : error messages from your code

`2>&1` redirects stderr output to stdout

`<`redirects stdin

Comment: The question is asking *why* it’s done, not what it does.

Comment: He seems a little confused so i'm explaining these mecanisms